# node-webkit app package creates nw.js empty screen

Tags: javascript, html, node-webkit

I have created the app using node-webkit . But when i click on gte.exe it giving nw.js empty scree.

my JSON file is:

```
{
    "main": "index.html",
    "name": "app",
    "description": "app",
    "version": "0.2.3",
    "nodejs": true,
    "window": {
        "title": "app",
        "icon": "favicon.ico",
        "toolbar": false,
        "frame": true,
        "width": 1200,
        "height": 768,
        "min_width": 1024,
        "min_height": 768,
        "resizable": true
    },
    "webkit" :{
        "plugin":true
    },

    "chromium-args": "--disable-web-security --experimental-location-features --enable-geolocation --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access --enable-device-policy"
```

[image]}

I changed my folder into zip and changed to .nw extension. After that i ran D:\nw>copy /b nw.exe+app.nw gte.exe .

Please any one help me out

Comment: Did you try to build with https://github.com/mllrsohn/node-webkit-builder ? Same result? Any messages in inspector?

Comment: I found what was the issue . Inside our app folder select all items (json,app.js,index.html) and right click then compress instead of right click and compressing the parent folder.